# SQL Report Builder 3.0 - Failed to preview report

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I have looked but have not been able to find another posted question that matches my scenario.

I am replicating a report from an old DB and rebuilding it using a new DB, so I'm simply copying the old report elements and pasting them into a new report template and modifying as needed. I've gotten to one part where the error I'm getting is as follows:

> The Color expression for the text box ‘Textbox94’ refers to the field
>   ‘Gallon_Qty’.  Report item expressions can only refer to fields within
>   the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified
>   dataset scope. Letters in the names of fields must use the correct
>   case.

I have looked everywhere I could possibly think to look to see where this issue is hiding, but cannot find where this textbox is 'referring' to anything. Since it appears to be specific to this textbox, I presume it is specific to the text box properties of that text box, but it seems I'm mistaken. For added clarity, what I have checked includes every menu option within the text box properties (General, Number, Alignment, Font, Border, etc.) and every fx (function) button to ensure nothing was hiding (that's gotten me before). I have compared with another report element that works similarly and cannot find where the problem is. Any tips on where else I might check to uncover the root of this issue? Happy to provide screenshots if it will help, just let me know.

Side note: I can't thank you guys enough for all the help I've gotten on here!

Comment: Is `Gallon_Qty` a calculated or query field added to the dataset in Report Builder?

Comment: Well, Gallon_Qty is actually a reference to the old report from which I'm copying, actually. I thought I'd be able to find where it is referencing this now defunct column, but no luck in finding it so I can change it to the correct column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered where the issue was.

Text Box Properties>Font>Color>fx box

This is where the value was hiding. Hope this helps someone else.